# cast integer to generic enum types that have a different underlying type

Tags: c#, generics, enums, casting

The function below only works when the parameter type is the same as the underlying type of `T`. How can I make it work for all enum? (I don't care about narrowing or widening)

```
public T Cast<T>(int i) where T : Enum
{
  return (T)(object)i;
}
```

Comment: Why do you even need this function? It's just making your code less readable and less efficient than casting directly, e.g. `var enumValue = (MyEnum)someInt`

Comment: What David says, but: the only advantage I could imagine is that you could include a [range check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.isdefined?view=net-5.0).

Comment: @DavidG I don't need this function. It is just a simplification for the question. I wish I can cast directly in my code but I can't.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Because that requires `i` to be a string? Also, I'd prefer the generic version here so `Enum.Parse<T>(i.ToString())`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Of course, I still don't know why OP can't use a simple cast, that makes no sense to me.

Comment: @DavidG The same reason I can't do it in function `Cast`, because `T` is a type parameter. The `Parse` works, but in i my case I think i'd better off just let it fail when underlying type mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that for example like this:

```
public static T Cast<T>(int i) where T : Enum {
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(i, Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)));
}
```